# Add checkbox in node menu settings

Tags: forms

I would like to add one checkbox in Menu settings at node /node/add/{Content types}

I am not sure how to do that.
I need to use ***Form and Controller***.

**What form I need to include?** This is some of them.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

And after I need to implemente Implements [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8).

**Is my thinking ok?**

[image]

Comment: Its look like I need to implemente hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter and use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8

Comment: Have you found a solution to identify the menu block where the Menu Settings resides? I am also trying to add fields to the Menu Settings and can't target that specific region correctly. My fields are being added to one of the other fieldsets.

Comment: No. I dont know how to add chackbox there like on photo..

Comment: Ok. If I manage to resolve this I'll post back.

Comment: Tnx you a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want a menu to appear only at a certain content type? It is not done from there.

In Drupal 8 each menu is a block; After you have created the menu regularly with the native API unchanged, just add the block to the desired region and then set that block to appear only in a certain region you want it to appear in (You should see such an option in the block's conf page).

Comment: I know. I would like to add checkbox  like on photo, what I change now in my first post. But I can not found code what control that. :(